# Почему в строчке if (list[i] == list[j]) индекс выходит за пределы массива?

Tags: c#, массивы

Если что вот задача:

Ваша программа так же получает на вход два числа в строковом формате, но теперь они  могут быть разной длины. Найдите все уникальные элементы первого числа (значения, которые встречаются  только 1 раз в обоих массивах)

Пример:

12335

1458

В данном случае уникально число 2 - оно существует в одном экземпляре

1 и 5 есть во втором массиве, а 3 встречается дважды в первом

В итоге ответ:

"Уникально число 2"

Sample Input:

12335
1458

Sample Output:

Уникально число 2

```
            string num1 = Console.ReadLine();
            string num2 = Console.ReadLine();
            string num = num1 + num2;
            char[] list = num.ToCharArray();
            string str = ""; 
            Console.WriteLine("Уникальное число ");
            foreach (int i in list)
            {
            foreach (int j in list)
            {
                if (i == j)
                    continue;
                if (list[i] == list[j]) // ошибка здесь!
                    continue;
                else
                    str += list[i];

            }
            Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: Переменные `i` и `j` - не индексы в списке `list`: [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/using-foreach-with-arrays).

Comment: Если хочешь использовать i и  j как индексы, используй цикл for, а не foreach.